# Netbiter Rest Server

Tags: json, rest, firemonkey

I am trying to access the data on a Rest Server in a Firemonkey Mobile app via a 
- TRestRequest
- TRestClient
- TRestResponse

I have set the baseurl to: "https://api.netbiter.net/operation/v1/rest/json"
and the resource to: "https://api.netbiter.net/operation/v1/rest/json/system"

the thing about this rest server is that you need to provide and accesskey and I don't know where to put that.  So the question is **How do I utilize the accesskey via Firemonkey?**

The Java example can be found [here](http://apidocs.netbiter.net/?page=methods&show=codeExampleJava) (to see how they implement the accesskey)

Answer (score 0):

```
RestClient := TRESTClient.Create('https://api.netbiter.net/operation/v1/rest/json/');    
Request := TRESTRequest.Create(RestClient);
Request.Resource := 'system?accesskey=' + accessKey;
Request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGet;
Request.Execute;
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this? Code only answers are considered low quality